# A single linear feasibility formulation that exactly captures all the optimal solutions of both primal and dual.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Given a linear program, we have the primal as follows:
\begin{array}{lll}
\max: & c^Tx\\
\text{s.t.} & Ax \leq b\\
& x\geq 0\\
\end{array}
And we also have the dual as follows:
\begin{array}{lll}
\min: & y^Tb\\
\text{s.t.} & y^TA \geq c\\
& y \geq 0\\
\end{array}

Now, the question is (a)to design a single linear feasibility formulation (i.e. Find $z$ such that $Bz \leq k$) that exactly captures all the optimal solutions of both primal and dual. (b)show that $(x^*,y^*)$ is feasible in the formulation if and only if $x^*$ is an optimal solution of the primal and $y^*$ is an optimal solution of the dual.

Here's what I got so far:
The single linear feasibility formulation is the following:

$\begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & -A^T \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} \leq \begin{pmatrix}b \\ -c^T\end{pmatrix}$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n},x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}, y\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$.

From this formulation, it should capture all the optimal solution of both primal and dual.
Now,for part (b), the converse direction is trivial because if $x^*$ is an optimal, then it means $Ax^* \leq b$ and $y^*$ is an optimal solution of the dual means $-A^Ty^* \leq -c^T$, so $z=(x^*,y^*)$ is feasible in the formulation.

However, I am stuck in the forward direction, which is if $(x^*,y^*)$ is feasible in the formulation, then $x^*$ is an optimal solution of the primal and $y^*$ is an optimal solution of the dual. Can I get some help for that? Do I have to use the strong duality theorem in order to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to impose the duality constraint as well, that is $c^Tx \ge y^Tb$.

Also, don't forget the sign constraint, which is $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.

---

Here is the equivalent single linear feasibility formulation which captures optimal solution of primal and dual:

\begin{align}
-c^Tx &\le -y^Tb \\
x &\ge 0 \\
y &\ge 0 \\
Ax &\le b \\
-A^Ty &\le -c
\end{align}

You just have to write it as a single inequality.

---

Edit:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -c^T & b^T \\ -I & 0 \\ 0 & -I \\ A & 0 \\ 0 & -A^T\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \le \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\ 0\\ 0  \\ b  \\ -c\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You mean imposing the strong duality constraint ($c^Tx = y^Tb$) in the proof of the forward direction or in the original linear feasibility formulation? For the forward direction, are we trying to show that if $(x^*,y^*)$ are feasible, and if we can show $c^Tx^* = y^*Tb$, then we can conclude $(x^*,y^*)$ are optimal? Can you explain more about the forward direction of the proof?

Comment: I mean the formulation. your formulation is not equivalent yet.

Comment: So I was able to get something like this $\begin{pmatrix}A & -1 \\ -1 & -A^T \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} \leq \begin{pmatrix}b \\ -c\end{pmatrix}$. But I am stuck at trying to impose those two inequalities $c^Tx \leq y^Tb$ and $-c^Tx \leq -y^Tb$ in the matrix, can you give me some hint how to do that or am I on the right track?

Comment: I have written them in matrix form.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I was stuck at thinking the matrix should be in $\mathbb{R}^{(n+m)x(n+m)}$

Comment: The weak duality constraint is redundant, so you need to enforce only one side of the equality.

Comment: you are right, thanks.